# How to access USB Path in android?

Tags: android

I am connected android device and PC via USB cable. My Internal SD Card location Path as `/mnt/sdcard`. But my External USB device path as `/mnt/userdata1`. I am try to use this code to find only the Internal SD Card Path `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`. I am using this code to access only in the internal SD Card path. How to access the external USB Path.

For example Screenshot is here... 
[Example](http://www.androidfreeapp.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/astro-file-manager-android-tablet-app-1024x640.jpg)

In this example contains `Internal Memory`, `External SD card` and `USB Storage`. How to find this path ( `Internal Memory`, `External SD card` and `USB Storage`) programmatically. In this code `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` is viewed files from all `Internal Memory` Files only. So how to access others path ( `External SD card` and `USB Storage` )
 Please guide me with code. Thanks..

Comment: So what exactly is the problem that you are having?

Comment: I know th internal sd card path. But how to find the external usb device path. I have no idea.

Comment: One thing to remember when working with external storage: you must include permissions. Writing to external storage requires `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Comment: Maybe is not the most elegant solution, but this work on most devices: Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("df");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you are calling "external" USB path is actually the mount point for your SD card on your computer.  Most likely, your SD card has label `userdata1`.  Therefore when it's mounted on the computer, it gets `/mnt/userdata1` mount point.  However this is not strictly necessary and it can be any mount point at all.  In fact, if you connect it to another computer, it can easily be another mount point.

Because this path is determined by the computer operating system, you'll need to find this path on your computer (note that this can be different every time you connect your phone to your PC, so you'll need to do it every time).

From your question and path structure (`/mnt/userdata1`) I'm guessing you're using linux or some other unix version.  Therefore you could run `mount` on your PC to see the list of the mounted devices.  For example, here's the output on my mac:

```
$ mount
/dev/disk0s2 on / (hfs, local, journaled)
devfs on /dev (devfs, local, nobrowse)
map -hosts on /net (autofs, nosuid, automounted, nobrowse)
map auto_home on /home (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
/dev/disk1s1 on /Volumes/ALEKS540 (msdos, local, nodev, nosuid, noowners)
```

Note the last line in the output - this is my connected android phone with the SD card mounted to the computer.  On macs, the mount points are created under `/Volumes` instead of `/mnt`.  Other than than, *ALEKS540* is the label of my SD card, hence it's mounted this way.

Internally on the phone, it's still mounted as `/mnt/sdcard`.

From the point of view of Android, there may be three storage types:

1. **Internal memory** it's always mounted under `/` on the device and contains everything except the SD card and USB storage below.
2. **SD card** - this is referred to as "external storage" and is usually mounted as `/mnt/sd`, but not always.  `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` will return the path of SD card mount point.
3. **USB storage** - this is only supported on very few devices (those that support USB host mode for external storage).  This will be mounted somewhere under `/mnt`, but the exact location will vary.  You will need to use Android NDK to interrogate and iterate mounted devices to find the one you're after.