# Android not enough storage memory

Tags: android, android-external-storage, capacity, android-usb

I created an `Android` `app` sometime ago. What the `app` does is basically download a list of files (images and videos) and play them in a loop (like a `Playlist`).

These files are saved in the default `Android External Storage Directory`. I get it using this method:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
```

Until now I never had storage problems but testing the `app` on an old device (which has less storage capacity) I realised that I have a problem when the files (`PlayList`) size is bigger than the device storage capacity.

I have thought (and research) about using an `USB` stick, but I don't think that would be a good solution since I cannot know 100% sure the `USB` path (it can be different for each device).

Any ideas about how handle this problem? Maybe another solution instead of using the `USB` ?

Here is what I have researched:

[How to access USB Path in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291882/how-to-access-usb-path-in-android)

[How to find USB storage path programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30976189/how-to-find-usb-storage-path-programmatically)

[android How to write files to a usb memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15696173/android-how-to-write-files-to-a-usb-memory)

Comment: you can use libraries like picasso to handle image download and caching which I think better solution for you

Comment: Hey @Pooya thans for your comment. We are not talking about a OOM error, that's fine I already use Picasso for that. The problem is that the files I need to download are bigger than my device storage capacity

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to store the actual images and videos on the device - why not just store their location and get them dynamically. I've not used a recyclerView but I thought that it could do something like this, but could be wrong.

Comment: I need to store the files on the device memory because the `app` should work in offline mode. So the user sync the data (download the files from a server), store the data on the device and it should work without internet connection.

Comment: Btw it doesn't have anything to do with a RecyclerView or ListView. But thanks for taking the time to read and answer, really appreciate it :)